# Make change without using !important modifier -- rule of specificity?

Tags: javascript, css, ascx

I have a div in Foo.ascx like so:

```
<div id="myIdentifier" class="myCssClass">
```

It is nested in serveral DPanels, etc. I need to set the height of this div to 80px. When I add `height: 80px;` to myCssClass, it doesn't work. If I add the important modifier to that line of code so that it is `height: 80px !important;`, it does work. I need to (preferably) change the height without the important modifier, or understand why it is necessary.

The only other references to myIdentifier (and thus the div) are in FooBehavior.js. Within FooBehavior.js, the only things that happen are appending a child element and changing the width.

Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: You need to include all of your CSS. You have other CSS on the page with higher specificity. We can't tell you how to have higher specificity for a CSS property if we don't know the other rules it has to be higher than.

Comment: If you right-click the element and choose "inspect" the browser's development tools will open. Choosing the element will display the CSS rules that apply to it and you will be able to see which rule is taking precedence over yours. Once you see that rule, you will have to change yours so that it is more specific. But, without knowing what that other rule is, we really can't say definitively what your rule needs to be.

Comment: Using your browser's style inspector, see what rule is overriding your `myCssClass` rule. That will tell you what you need to do to make your rule for this more specific than that (or equally specific but defined after it so it takes precedence). Note, though, that ID rules are fairly specific, so `#myIdentifier.myCssClass { height: 80px; }` may be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stronger definition, like this:

First is just a class identifier,
Second is "a div which has class myCssClass"
Third one is "a div's child which has class myCssClass"
And so on..

```css
.myCssClass {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: black;
  }

div .myCssClass {
    background-color: blue;
  }

div > .myCssClass {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">

  <div id="myIdentifier" class="myCssClass" />
  
</div>
```